# Process Environment Block в MemorySharp

Tags: c#

Нашел библиотеку [Memory Sharp](http://binarysharp.com/products/memorysharp/)

Там написано, что при помощи библиотеки можно взаимодействовать с его PEB.

В PEB есть параметр `CommandLine` и мне нужно его изменить.

```
var sharp = new MemorySharp((int)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle.ToInt32());
var peb = sharp.Peb;
```

Переменная `peb` не содержит `CommandLine`. Подскажите, может кто работал с этой библиотекой, как изменить данный параметр?

(В [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992786/how-to-clear-a-process-command-line/3992953#3992953) ответе есть решение на C++, но я с ним не дружу. Совсем. И библиотеку собрать тоже не смогу, не предлагайте даже)

Данный код не помогает, однако при закрытии вызывает краш.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "test";
p.Start();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1400);

var sharp = new MemorySharp(p.Id);

var peb = sharp.Peb;

peb.ProcessParameters = IntPtr.Zero;
```

Comment: Я немного глянул эту библиотеку, но так и не понял как она предлагает с собой работать. Единственно, что я понял, как мне кажется, что с помощью библиотеки Вы получаете адрес `peb.ProcessParameters` и остаётесь с ним один на один. Т.е. дальше Вам нужно воспользоваться [документацией](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa813741(v=vs.85).aspx) для вычисления сдвига до command line args, а потом воспользоваться `MemorySharp.Write` для записи туда данных. Так я это понял, хотя мои познания в C# ограничены и может кто-то подскажет лучше.

Comment: А как вычислить сдвиг?

Comment: @ixSci, не получается вычислить.
Мне нужен оффсет, а он только в C++

Comment: Можно посмотреть в дебаггере, что там в памяти, куда указывает возвращённый IntPtr. Найти там cmd args и посмотреть по какому они смещению находятся. Но это всё сложно, непонятно какой тогда смысл в этой библиотеке, когда она на даёт высокоуровневого доступа.